# Jumping of electron

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-information, atomic-physics

When an electron goes from higher energy level to lower energy level, it emits energy in the form of light. Then why an object thrown from a certain height to a lower height does not emit energy in the form of light?

Comment: There exists radiationless transitions: That is, transitions between energy states, that do not emit radiation. They simply contribute to heat. Some [lasers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_inversion#Creating_a_population_inversion) works because of this. So, an electron going from higher energy to low energy, does not need to always emit radiation.

Answer (score 1):

> When an electron goes from higher energy level to lower energy level, it emits energy in the form of light. Then why an object thrown from a certain height to a lower height does not emit energy in the form of light?

Electrons are elementary particles , quantum mechanical entities obeying quantum mechanics.  The energy levels are because of the quantum mechanical nature. One of the reasons quantum mechanics had to be invented was because of the existence of the hydrogen atom and the spectra [giving quantized energy levels,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html#c2) instead of the continuum. The classical solution for an electron around a proton would just have the electron radiate continually until it hit the proton, so no hydrogen atom could exist. That led to the need to develop  quantum mechanics.

For a macroscopic object with no charge falling on a neutral ground there will be no radiation.Radiation is an effect between charges .

[This lecture](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/nuclear-engineering/22-105-electromagnetic-interactions-fall-2005/readings/chap4.pdf) covers the mathematics of *classical* radiation from a charged particle.

For a charged macroscopic object  attracted and falling on an oppositely charged object there will be a continuum of radiation, as predicted by classical electrodynamics, the charges can be  modeled  mathematially in space by hypothetical point particles.

Macroscopic objects usually contain an order of  10^23  molecules ( avogadro's number) which leads to [statistical decoherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_decoherence) of any quantum mechanical effecs. Only in special conditions quantum mechanical properties can be retained, as in superconductivity and superfluidity, and some laser setups.